# Flow is not available in kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

`kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow` is not available with     `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'`, but is available with     `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.0'`.

Is it depricated? What is alternative?

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface WordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): Flow<List<Word>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Kotlin Flow is not deprecated. Use the latest version of `kotlinx-coroutine-android` (1.5.2): `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.2`

It works for me.

Comment: Thx! That did the trick :-)